# average rating calculation mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate average rating of every user.

I have three table.

table rating

```
id |order_id |rate
------------------
1  | 52      |8
2  | 51      |4
3  | 52      |2
4  | 51      |7
```

Table order

here did is driver table id

```
id |did
------------------
52  | 5 
51  | 7 
35  | 6 
44  | 8
```

Table driver

```
id |name 
------------------
5  | test1 
7  | test2 
8  | test3 
6  | test4
```

my sql query is

```
select dr.name,AVG(drate.rate) from `rating` as drate,`order` as ord,`driver` as dr where ord.did=dr.id and drate.order_id=ord.id
```

my query always give result only one .

here i want to select average rate from rating table but relation is rating table order_id= order table id and order table did =driver table id

that means

```
order_id(rating table) |id(order table) |id(driver table) |rate
-------------------------------------------------------------------
52                     | 52             |5                |avg(8,2)
51                     | 51             |7                |avg(4,7)
```

Comment: Try using constructive field names. You have ID for all three tables, just makes things confusing.

Comment: i already Update my question here did is driver table id @AzizSaleh

Answer (score 4):

If order.did is user Id, then

```
select order.did, AVG(rate) from rating
join order on order.id = drate.id
group by order.did
```

Comment: see i describe briefly

Comment: sill understand what do you want, gourp by user is not possible?